# Taxonomy to Post Type. Every Taxonomy Item can be Producer or Developer

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

Problem:

- I need to associate to every PostType a Company(done with Taxonomy, taxonomy is a huge list of Companies)
- A company can be a Producer or a Developer
- I need to Select a Producer on the PostType
- I need to Select a Developer on the PostType

As you understand you can have the same Company as Developer and Producer

**Solution ?**

Unfortunately i find myself like a fish out of water. Wordpress is the perfect CMS for this Job but for this task, ehmmm, i dont know :/ 
According my background i can associate a Company to a Post Type (Company will be the Taxonomy). But after ? How to do an intermediate Association (every Company can be a Developer, Publisher or Both) ?

P.S I Dont need meta fields (i need to insert at least 2000 companies if not more than that, custom fields will slow down hard i think the queries if i start to search a developer who has done x PostType)

Thanks in advance to each of you for your time, I do not owe you a beer, I owe you a ticket for the World Cup final if you give me a hand, I'm banging my head against the wall two days for that ...... :/ :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to use plugin, you can use PostType (avoid taxonomies) for both entities using this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/

Documented here: https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki

Comment: Not sure whether it is a good idea to recommend a plugin that is clearly not in active development anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In your example I think it would be better that Companies are also a post type and not a taxonomy.

Then with plugins like [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) or [Toolset](https://toolset.com/) it is possible to make connections between post types.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks for your time and your suggestions. Im already using my handmade plugin (with cmb2, json, seo classes, etc, etc...) and im terrified/scaried to use something like toolset (my impression is the classic super bloated plugin useful mostly for end user).
Your ideas are ok and i really appreciate your time but, as i said, to use Custom Field is a no way (that's my personal idea) when you have huuge amount of data for many to many.
**I've found the solution** at https://wordpress.org/plugins/npc-neatekpostconnect/.
 It's a plugin but it's :

- tiny (+1)
- it has clear classes (+1)
- it creates 2 tables (perfect for many to many relationship)

I dont know the impact of the plugin in server load (or if it requires some tweaks) but according code sounds like a great solution for many to many and a great solution for everyone involved in this.